Benefits of subdividing components that use AD for derivatives
One of the main benefits of using OpenMDAO is that it facilitates the derivatives computation of the full model. In a model that I'm working on, AD is used to compute the partials of the most computationally-intensive component of the model. How much benefit would I get from splitting the component into separate subcomponents? I would still provide the derivatives of the subcomponents using AD.
I am trying to find mentions of specific benefits that arise from this approach in the literature, but didn't manage to identify anything about advantages of splitting AD computations into smaller ones to provide "simpler" partials to an adjoint process for derivatives.

One of the benefits of using many subcomponents vs. one big component is it allows you to setup a hierarchical linear solver approach for the adjoint (to be more precise, the UDE linear system). Depending on the model's coupling structure, a hierarchical linear solver can be much faster than a "monolithic" linear solver applied to a model with a few big components. The appropriate linear solver setup is highly problem-dependent, though. This benefit is about the linear solves for the total derivative computations, and not about computing partials. So it might not be relevant to your questions on AD for partials.
Note: I'm not an OpenMDAO developer and I could be wrong.

My questions was more about understanding the benefits on the "quality" of the AD derivatives, but what you mentioned is another relevant benefit of splitting the component that I wasn't thinking about, so thanks for your reply!

In general I would expect performance to be somewhat better with fewer components. Those calculations within the compute methods of the components won't need to involve the transfer of data from one system to another.
Depending on how the AD handled implicit behavior is may make sense to have openmdao handle the solving if residuals.  But if the AD library is computing derivative "around" the nonlinear solver rather than "through" it, then I wouldn't anticipate a problem with one component with the AD library solvers inside of it's compute method.

I understand the point about fewer components being better in terms of performance, because of the overhead involved in data transfer.
Can you elaborate on the second part of your answer? Specifically, what does it mean for AD to compute the derivatives around/through the nonlinear solver, and how should that impact the choice of splitting the component into multiple components or not? Thank you!

To expand upon the "around" vs "through" the solver part of my previous answer...
If I write a newton solver in JAX, Julia, or whatever your AD library of choice is, use it to solve for some state x given that state's residual, and then AD that process, the AD will perform automatic differentiation on the newton solver itself.  This typically involves a lot of mathematical steps, so it can be expensive and build up inaccuracy.
Another way to achieve this is to just solve for the derivatives of the implicit outputs (y) relative to the inputs to the methods being solved (x) by assuming the total derivative of the residual with respect to x is zero. Intuitively, if we tweak our inputs, re-solve the system, the residuals went from zero to zero...the total derivative of the residual is therefore zero.
The OpenMDAO paper and other sources go into this in a lot more detail than I can here, but the gist of it is that you can solve the derivatives of the implicit outputs y as a function of the inputs x by setting up a linear system to do so. No re-convergence of the system is necessary, as it would be with finite differencing. Solving the derivatives this way makes doing so completely independent of the method used to drive the residuals to zero.
I'd recommend picking up the OpenMDAO paper, or reading about the topic in Engineering Design Optimization by Martins and Ning.
